# Sinatra static assets empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, assets, rails-routing

I have a Sinatra app in a Rails app that serves a static asset from a directory. The app is mounted in the Rails routes like this:

`mount BeanstalkdView::Server, :at => "/beanstalk"`

When I run this locally it works fine, using Thin, but when I run it on my test server (Nginx/Passenger) the static assets behave strange. A request to a static file return 200 OK, but there is no content.

I tell Sinatra where my static files are via `set :public_folder, "#{root}/resources"` and in the template I load the static files, e.g. a CSS file with `#{request.env['SCRIPT_NAME']}/css/file.css`. I verified that both paths are correct.

Comment: When you open up developer tools, are you getting any errors in the net tab?

Comment: No, status is 200 OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aleksey V's answer helped me a lot. In the end I fixed this using the proper setting for Nginx in `production.rb`:

`config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'`

Make sure you restart your Rails app, Nginx and do a hard refresh in your browser to get the files.

For more info check out: http://jimneath.org/2011/04/05/rails-3-nginx-and-send_file.html.

Answer (score 3):

That happens due to `::Rack::Sendfile` middleware which is enabled by default in Rails 3.0.x in production (disabled by default in any environment since 3.1.x).

This middleware is really simple but yet powerful. When you pass `::Rack::File` or `::Sinatra::StaticFile` (or any other object) which respond to `:path`, this middlware adds `X-SendFile` (for Apache) or `X-SendFile-Redirect` (for NGinx) and does not sends actual body. So that Apache or NGinx will handle real file delivery. It's a good and most efficient way to serve static assets in production, however you may disable this middleware (if you don't want to mess with your Nginx/Apache config). Find and comment following config option in your `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header
```

this config option is used to instruct `Sendfile` middleware which header to set (do not do anything if not specified).